# determining DOM element media style using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I want to know the `display` CSS of a DOM element. Normally I would using something like `document.getElementById('hello-world').style.display` but when the style is being set using CSS @media Rule I do not see any change to this value.

Any reason why?
And how would I be able to get this information.

Here is an example to demonstrate https://codepen.io/liywjl/pen/JjYyqVv

**Code:**
HTML

```
<p id="hello-world">Hello world</p>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  #hello-world {
    display: none;
  }  
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('hello-world').style.display)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('hello-world')).display
```

However, then can be a delay between the the setting of the style and the page re-flow and this may be not work on all browsers.